Nginx try_files with different headers based on file existance
How to add a different header if file exists on disk?
example:

set $somevariable = /test/test1/1.html
#(this is set dynamicaly based on request, but for this example i made this a static string)

location / {
  add_header TEST "from /";
  try_files $somevariable $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location = /test/ {
  add_header TEST "BAD";
  try_files $somevariable $uri $uri/;
}

location = /test/test1/1.html {
  add_header TEST "GOOD";
}

curl -I https://example.com/test/
returns TEST BAD. and i want to return GODD if test/test1/1.html exists, and BAD otherwise.
curl -I https://example.com/
returns TEST from /
